# Finding the original matrix given the Gramian Matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication, transpose

I'm trying to find the contents of matrix `A` given that `A * A.T = X`

I know that `A` (and therefore `A.T`) is a 5x5 matrix and I know the contents of `X`:

```
[
[-5608529.85751958,-1078099.28424021,782266.19092291,-5553202.27739048,-8346599.92810626], 
[-1078099.28424021, -10655907.3511596 , -217503.83572109,-4964009.33281077,-7389416.05437836],
[782266.19092291,-217503.83572109,-1630229.70928628,-6085405.40152081,-9213840.50324483],
[-5553202.27739048,-4964009.33281078,-6085405.40152081,-6529161.83967772,8491769.6736334],
[-8346599.92810626,-7389416.05437838,-9213840.50324484,8491769.67363339, -11725726.66921404]
]
```

How can I compute `A` efficiently in python?

For Reference: [Wikipedia: Gramian Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix)

Comment: I am not sure if SO is the place for this question, unless you specifically state you want a method using `numpy` (for example).

Comment: essentially yes. I need to do this for several matrices. Was hoping someone could provide a general methodology. (Using numpy or any other module).

Comment: This is completely outside of my expertise so you may like to research the mathematical function for reversing a Gramian matrix and then checking how to do each of the operations. You may encounter problems though if you have not calculated the matrix yourself as a quick Google mentioned something about time being involved in calculating the Gramian.